# Can a wizard learn spells from other wizards in the same group?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, dnd-adventurers-league

In Adventurer's League, can a wizard learn spells from another wizard in the same group?

In that case would the downtime days should be subtracted from both of the wizards involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes. You get eight hours a day per downtime day.

This can be found at the bottom of page 6, into page 7 of the [DDAL FAQs](http://dndadventurersleague.org/category/faq/)

This equates to 4 levels of spells per downtime day:

> For each level of the spell, the process takes 2 hours and costs 50 gp.

*Note: both the wizard doing the copying and the wizard with the spellbook being copied must expend downtime days.*

Comment: I don't see why the wizard with the spellbook being copied would have to spend downtime days, unless he distrusts the wizard doing the copying and wants to watch the process.  Can you explain your thinking on this?

Comment: @Phil Its not my thinking. It's the way the rules for adventurers league are written.

Comment: OK.  I'm not familiar with those rules.  I wouldn't run it that way; I assume that's a game balance thing.

Comment: As David said, the relevant section of the FAQ: "For each downtime day spent copying spells, a character may spend eight hours copying spells into their spellbook. Two or more characters participating in the same adventure together at the same table that choose to perform this downtime activity may allow one another access to their spellbook; effectively “trading” spells between everyone involved to copy as normal. Both parties to the trade must perform this downtime activity to trade spells." It adds that since there's a chance of failure, this activity must be done in the DM's presence.

Comment: my understanding is that both parties spend the downtime due to the fact that the original copy is in the original mage's "code" and he is required to "translate" his code for the new mage.

Comment: If a fellow wizard has to “translate” his code for their party member, then how does a wizard learn a spell from a scroll they find on their own.  The time and gold expenditures for learning a spell on their own would, logically, DECREASE if they don’t have to figure it out on their own.  If anything, a fellow wizard “translating” their code should decrease downtime for the learning wizard.